# Position div on edges of div, vertically centered

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to achieve the following look on a website I am working on. Notice how the `+` and `X` buttons are aligned vertically on the edges of the image on the center of the page. I am able to achieve this effect using some JavaScript to move around the divs containing the buttons. However, this solution doesn't work in Firefox or IE. Only in Chrome and Safari (webkit).

[image: Demo Image]

HTML

```
<div id="contest_image">
    <img id="single_image" src="/img/ajax-loader.gif"/>

    <div class="large_vote_no downvoteclick">
        <label for="large_no"><img src="/img/sprite_imgs/contest/vote_no.png" class="down_vote"/></label>
        <button id="large_no"></button>
    </div> 
    <div class="large_vote_yes upvoteclick">
        <label for="large_yes"><img src="/img/sprite_imgs/contest/vote_yes.png" class="down_vote"/></label>
        <button id="large_yes"></button>
    </div>

    <div id="share">
        <label class="grey">Share</label>
        <ul class="social_icons">
            <li><a href="" class="twit"></a></li>
            <li><a class="fb"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#/" class="email"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function position_vote_buttons() {
    $(".large_vote_yes").css("visibility","visible");
    $(".large_vote_no").css("visibility","visible");
    $("#single_image").css("border","2px solid #0097fa");    

    var position = $("#single_image").position();
    var width = $("#single_image").width();
    var height = $("#single_image").height();
    $(".large_vote_no").animate({
        left: position.left-80,
        top: position.top +(height / 2) - 70
    },0);
    $(".large_vote_yes").animate({
        left: position.left+width-77,
        top: position.top +(height / 2) - 70
    },0);
}
```

CSS

```
.large_vote_yes, .large_vote_no {
    width:70px;  
    display:inline;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    z-index:9999;
    visibility:hidden;
}
#large_yes, #large_no {
    border:none;
}
div#contest_image {
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto 5px;
    width:800px;
    max-height:600px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-align:center;
}
div#contest_image #single_image  {
    display:inline;
    vertical-align:middle;
    max-width:600px;
    max-height:600px;   
    position:relative;
    border:2px solid #;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;  
}
div#contest_image .up_vote, div#contest_image .down_vote {
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    display:inline;
}
```

Can anyone help to get these buttons to align properly across all modern browsers?

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap the image and 'button elements; in a single parent div the `button elements` can be positioned and transformed into place.

Note this works regardless of the image size.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8dL9uv1w/1/)

```css
body {
  margin: 25px;
  /* just for spacing */
}
.img-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.img-wrap img {
  display: block
}
.up,
.down {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
.up {
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
.down {
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrap">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-200-300-3.jpg" />
  <div class="up">Up</div>
  <div class="down">down</div>
</div>
```

Comment: just be sure to add your browser prefixes to cover your bases: `-webkit-transform: translate(50%, 50%);` etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible with just CSS/HTML. You need to know your image container height and your button size to get it perfect, though (which shouldn't be an issue in this case).

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/gxr4r2n0/1/

I placed the buttons inside the wrapper, and set the wrapper to `position:relative;`. Then, set the buttons to `position:absolute` and modify the `top`, `left`, `right`, and `margin-top` respectively based on which side the button is on and the size of the button.

This example is also responsive.